# PeopleQuickstart doesn't work with scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.other.readonly

Tags: google-people-api

I am trying to get PeopleQuickstart work with the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.other.readonly`

When I run with

```
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(PeopleServiceScopes.CONTACTS_READONLY);
```

it shows the direct contacts (without Other contacts),
However when I change the scopes to

```
 private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(                                                            
                                               PeopleServiceScopes.CONTACTS_READONLY,
                                              "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.other.readonly"                                               
                                                );
```

I still don't get the Other contacts. Any idea why

Comment: By `PeopleQuickstart` you mean [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/java)?

Comment: @JoseVasquez Correct, I wrote the name of the class.

Answer (score 2):

You must get "Other Contacts" using a different method https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/otherContacts/list